# Can one count the matches of multiple strings in one list?

Tags: python, list, counter

I do not want to count the occurrence of one item but multiple items. The variable `match` contains a list of strings. I want to search the target list how many of the `match` items are in the target list.

```
match = ["Manager", "Access Responsible"]
```

My dictionary contains the following entries:

```
dict = {'WF:ACAA-CR (auto)': ['Manager', 'Access Responsible', 'Automatic'],
    'WF:ACAA-CR-AccResp (auto)': ['Manager', 'Access Responsible', 'Automatic'], 
    'WF:ACAA-CR-IT-AccResp[AUTO]': ['Group', 'Access Responsible', 'Automatic']}
```

My code at the moment is:

```
for key, values in dict.items():
    val = values
    match = "Manager"
    c = Counter(val)
    print(key, c[match])
```

Output is:

```
WF:ACAA-CR (auto) 1
WF:ACAA-CR-AccResp (auto) 1
WF:ACAA-CR-IT-AccResp[AUTO] 0
```

That is fine and I want something like that, but with finally six items in `match`.

I tried:

```
for key, values in dict.items():
    val = values
    match = ["Manager", "Access Responsible"]
    c = Counter(val)
    print(key, c[match])
```

The error message is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/extract.py", line 29, in 
>       print(key, c[match])
>   TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

**How do I count the matches of more than one string in a list?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply loop over your `match` list and look for each element. Also, I don't see why you need an extra variable `val`.

The problem with your code was that you were trying to pass a complete list `match` as an argument to the output of `Counter` which is a dictionary. So you were trying to use two values of your `match` list as the key. Hence you got the error.

```
match = ["Manager", "Access Responsible"]

for key, values in dict_2.items():
    val = values
    c = Counter(val)
    for m in match:
        print(key, c[m])
```

---

```
WF:ACAA-CR (auto) 1
WF:ACAA-CR (auto) 1
WF:ACAA-CR-AccResp (auto) 1
WF:ACAA-CR-AccResp (auto) 1
WF:ACAA-CR-IT-AccResp[AUTO] 0
WF:ACAA-CR-IT-AccResp[AUTO] 1
```

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick. Now I will just take the sum so I do not have multiple lines but one line with the sum of the matches.

Comment: You are welcome. One way could be to simply make a list and store the occurrences in that and then print the total sum later.

Comment: Yes, that was my idea too.